# RSA sign error with SHA384

Tags: c#, rsa

I've made this code

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSASign = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                    StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("PublicPrivate.txt");
                    string myKey = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sr.Close();

                    RSASign.FromXmlString(myKey);

                    byte[] signature = RSASign.SignData(arr, new SHA384CryptoServiceProvider());

                    string head = "<!>Signature</!>";

                    byte[] headBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(head);

                    byte[] arrayToSend = new byte[headBytes.Length + signature.Length];

                    arrayToSend = headBytes.Concat(signature).ToArray();

                    UserSock.Send(arrayToSend);
```

And I'm facing this problem in my computer everythings works fine, but when I copy the exe file inside on a different computer I receive an error on the RSASign.SignData() function.
Is it possible that the problem is related to a different .net framework version. On my computer I have version 4.5 and i tested it on some computers with 3.5 and 4.
Otherwise I don't what should be the problem. I'm sure the the RSA private key is read properly.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Which error did it raise?

Comment: I add a try/catch that sorround the signdata, but the only error that i can receive is an invalid value.

Comment: Ok I guess is not a problem related to framework version, since I tried to compile the program with version 4 and 3.5

Comment: Ok I guess that I solved the problem. I replaced new SHA384CryptoServiceProvider() with "SHA384"

Comment: Could you post that as an answer, Francesco? Then we can upvote and you can accept the answer after a while, so it is considered answered.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to replace `new SHA384CryptoServiceProvider()` with `"SHA384"`
I found also that this is a problem related to Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

There's an MSDN Blog dealing with SHA256:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2008/08/25/using-rsacryptoserviceprovider-for-rsa-sha256-signatures.aspx

It explains that you can't pass a SHA256CryptoServiceProvider, but that:

> The second parameter should be either the string "SHA256", the type of
>   the SHA256Managed object, or an instance of a SHA256Managed object.

...which refers to the "red" and "green" model,(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2006/05/18/601354.aspx).